# How do we edit css in framework?

Tags: php, css, model-view-controller, frameworks

I'm builing an simple mvc-framework with an admin-panel where I can perform CRUD operations (ie Create, Read, Update, Delete), upload pictures and change css. My question is how do we change css from an admin-panel? As an example, how can I change my background color, header background image etc...?

I coudn't find information about this subject. I only found something about inserting php in the css-pages. I thought it was some sort of by-pass and thought there must be an better way.

Comment: I'm not completely sure in understand, but can you not just change or add a class/id where ever needed (using js/jQuery) to change colors based on the respective css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a colorpicker for determining the colours for everything, store them in your database for reference.

To use them you could call them directly in your template.html file with something like this:

```
<body style="background-color:$color">$content</body>
```

But assuming you want this in your .css file, you give your .css file a .php extension and add this in the top of the file:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

And then use the appropriate code to retrieve the variables and paste them in between the static css. This is the bypass.

Or just overwrite a .css file everytime you change the colors, but be sure to remember that if you ever need to edit your css you need to edit the template of that css first and then save the colors into that new template again.

Comment: This is what i was questening about. Is this the best way or is the solution @leigh commented better? i`m finding it strange that you just closed me down i think it is really worth the question but ok. although thank you for your answers.